# Parsing xml (storing only selected data)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, xml-parsing

i have an xml output from a webservice in a variable "results"

it looks something like this,

```
<ArrayOfSeriesRecord xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="http://hiscentral.cuahsi.org/20100205/">

<SeriesRecord>
<ServCode>IIHRTippingB</ServCode>
<ServURL>
http://his08.iihr.uiowa.edu/tippingbucket/cuahsi_1_0.asmx?WSDL
</ServURL>
<location>IIHR:CC00</location>
<VarCode>IIHR:Precipitation</VarCode>
<VarName>Precipitation</VarName>
<beginDate>9/25/2006 12:00:00 AM</beginDate>
<endDate>5/7/2011 12:00:00 AM</endDate>
<ValueCount>161738</ValueCount>
<Sitename>CC00</Sitename>
<latitude>41.736152648925781</latitude>
<longitude>-91.931015014648438</longitude>
<datatype>Continuous</datatype>
<valuetype>FieldObservation</valuetype>
<samplemedium>Precipitation</samplemedium>
<timeunits>minute</timeunits>
<conceptKeyword>Precipitation</conceptKeyword>
<genCategory/>
<TimeSupport>15</TimeSupport>
</SeriesRecord>
```

i need to parse this xml to get the latitude and longitude and plot it on google maps..

any idea how i can do that..
please help

thanx in advance.. :))

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are 2 distinct steps; parse, then plot. IMHO putting both in the same question will reduce the number/quality of answers you get as you're asking for a lot of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite method for parsing xml is to use JAXB. You need an XML Schema Definition file that lays out how the XML will be structured. Then you use JAXB to generate Java classes that represent the elements. Then you can Marshal and Unmarshal XML/Data into and out of those objects.

```
//Read an XML file (or string, stream, etc...) into Java classes
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.my.jaxb.classes");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

JAXBElement<ArrayOfSeriesRecord> rootJaxb = (JAXBElement<ArrayOfSeriesRecord>)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("file.xml"));
ArrayOfSeriesRecord root = rootJaxb.getValue();
List<SeriesRecord> seriesRecords = root.getSeriesRecord();
```

Example of the XSD

```
//Example xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="ArrayOfSeriesRecord" type="ArrayOfSeriesRecordType"></xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfSeriesRecordType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="SeriesRecord" type="SeriesRecordType" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="SeriesRecordType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ServCode" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an xml parser (like tinyXml: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/) to parse the document, then simply select the longitude and latitude tags inner text values.